# Returning a sequence of numbers from an array?

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I've got a method which goes like this -

```
public IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size) {
//IntSequence is an interface and currently this thing is inside a class that's
//implementing it

    ArrayList<Integer> valuelist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = a1; i <= a2 + a1; i++)
    {
        if((a1 + a2) <= a.length)
        valuelist.add(a[i]);
    }
    return valuelist;
}
```

My problem here is, I just want to return a sequence of integers however what I am returning here is an ArrayList and the compiler says cannot convert from type IntSequence to ArrayList.

(I'm not allowed to change the parameters of the method)

Thanks for acknowledging the problem!

EDIT :

This is my IntSequence interface -

```
public interface IntSequence {

   int length();

   int get(int index);

   void set(int index, int value);

   IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size);
}
```

Comment: It seems like you would need to build an instance of `IntSequence`, well, a class that implements it, right?

Comment: Where is your IntSequence defined? Can you show the code?

Comment: You may be able to define a class that implements `IntSequence` and defines a constructor with an `ArrayList<Integer>` parameter.  But it's hard to give you any more help without seeing what `IntSequence` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing `IntSequence`, it's hard to give a specific answer.  But you probably want to do something like:

```
class ArrayIntSequence implements IntSequence {

    private ArrayList<Integer> arr;

    public ArrayIntSequence (ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public ... 
    // provide bodies for all the methods defined in IntSequence, implemented
    // using "arr"

}
```

and then your `return` statement in `subSequence` becomes

```
return new ArrayIntSequence(valuelist);
```

**EDIT:** now that you've included the definition of `IntSequence`, the implementation of `length`, `get`, and `set` are very simple using the similar `ArrayList` methods, and it looks like you've already got `subSequence` except that you can tweak it to use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size) {
    // ...
    final ArrayList<Integer> valuelist = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
    return new IntSequence() {
       // Compiler will tell you what to put here
    };
 }
```

The compiler will give you some errors, telling you what methods you need to implement in order to return an `IntSequence`. If this is too much you might want to create a new object of the class that implements the interface and see if you can pass just the right contents to a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your method implements a method that returns `IntSequence`. If you try to return an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead, you are not actually fulfilling the interface. You will need to convert the ArrayList to whatever IntSequence is and return that.